# How to include "redirectParameters" to confirmation URL on registration email?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

If a customer access an URL which requires customer to be logged (let's say `mydomain.com/myrestrictedpage`), Shopware tries to preseve the URL and then, after the login, customer is redirected to the wished url.

**==== Login url, not including future redirect:**

mydomain.com/account/login

**==== Login url including future redirect:**

mydomain.com/account/login?redirectTo=myrestrictedpage&redirectParameters%3D%7B%22mycustomkey%22%3A%22bad0ef8cf33e4dd79935b63ca6b8afa1%22%7D

Unfortunetaly, Shopware doesn't include "redirectParameters" param on "confirm url", on registration email, only "redirectTo" param.

See: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/2e7a104f7744fbe5186a761d860031d0263c8cb9/src/Core/Checkout/Customer/SalesChannel/RegisterRoute.php#L229

That's probably a bug. Because the URL is being redirected to `/myrestrictedpage` BUT as there is no param `mycustomkey` = `bad0ef8cf33e4dd79935b63ca6b8afa1`. The page response is 500, as mycustomkey param is missing, and it's a required param.

*The question is, following Shopware best practices:*

**How to include "redirectParameters" to confirmation URL on registration email?**

I'm expecting how to include "redirectParameters" to confirmation URL on registration email.